# How do I use conditional formatting of a cell based on a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to change the background color of a cell (B1) if any of the cells below (B2 to B80) have any content.

I know I can approach the challenge either by looking for null values in all the column range or looking for anything other than a null in any one cell of the range.

Trouble is I can't remember or work out how to do either :(

Can SKS help out. (It's Office 365)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In your Conditional Format formula, you can use the `COUNTA` function to count the number of cells that are not blank. Then use the `>` operator to give it the condition you want met.

```
=COUNTA(B2:B80)>0
```

This will check if the number of blank cells in the range `B2:B80` is greater than `0`. If it returns a number greater than `0`, it will trigger the conditional format.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helps. If this answers your question, feel free to use the check mark on the left to mark it accepted. This will let others who read your question know it has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is write a simple helper formula that checks if any cells in a range are blank. The helper function will display true/false and you can link the conditional formatting to the helper function. Something like this:

[image: Example]

Answer (score -1):

You can select B1 and use
Conditional Formatting, New Rule
Use a Formula to determine which cells to Format
In the box of `Format values where the formula is True` write:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B80)))>0`

and choose the Format you want and ok
What ever you write in the cells B2:B80 (Number or Text) will trig the conditional formatting and show the result

Comment: Tx Yass for suggesting. The @counta() function actually suits me better because the final formulae has three conditions depending on the number of cells in a column that has values - that was too complex to post, so I just kept it simple :)